# Trouble accessing nested array data using React useState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to use React's useState hook to store a nested array. The problem is that I can't access individual values from the nested array once I save it. Strangely, I can access the outer arrays, but I can't get individual elements within them. Example from the guitar tab application I'm building:

```
const TabBar = (props) =>{

const [tabData, setTabData] = useState([]);
const rows=20

let initialTab = []
for (let x=0; x<rows;x++){
    initialTab.push(['-','-','-','-','-','-'])
}

useEffect(() => {    


    setTabData(initialTab)

}, []);

console.log(tabData)//this works
console.log(tabData[0]) //this works
console.log(tabData[0][0]) //this gives me 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'
```

Comment: what is output of `tabData[0]`?

Comment: `useEffect` runs after the render phase, the state update from inside `useEffect` is not completed by the time you try to log the values

Comment: Also you don't access the outer arrays, you are accessing an undefined index at position 0. this looks like a fixed state to me, just initialize it with the desired array instead of updating after mount

Comment: Random:, I'd get 'tabdata :  (6) ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]'

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because the it's trying to access that index before the effect runs and fills the array. Without knowing more context around the component you're writing, it looks like you want the array to initially be filled with those values, therefore I would suggest setting that as your default state. For example:

```
const defaultState = new Array(20).fill(["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]);

export default function App() {
  const [tabData, setTabData] = React.useState(defaultState);

  console.log(tabData); //this works
  console.log(tabData[0]); //this works
  console.log(tabData[0][0]);

  return (
    <div>anything</div>
  );
}
```

Then call `setTabData` whenever you need to make updates to this array.